# Leray spectral sequence for complexes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of schemes. Let 
$0\rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_3 \rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of Abelian sheaves on $X$. Is there a general procedure to relate the cohomology groups $H^p(S,R^qf_{*}C_i)$? I am interested in couples $(q,p)\in\{0,1,2\}^2\setminus (0,0)$